# NSUInteger oddities with for loops

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuinteger

I use AppCode to tweak the code I've written in XCode.  AppCode does awesome code inspections, and tells you where things can be improved.

One of the frequent inspections I come across points out that `[SomeObjCFrameworkClass objectAtIndex]` is expecting an `NSUInteger` which is in fact true...

```
- (ObjectType)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

however, I keep finding myself getting screwed by trying to follow this advice and change my `int`s to `NSUInteger`s.

For example, here's one piece of code that exploded when I did this change...

```
-(void)removeBadge
{
    if ([[theButton subviews] count]>0)
    {
        NSUInteger initalValue = [[theButton subviews] count]-1;
        //Get reference to the subview, and if it's a badge, remove it from it's parent (the button)
        for (NSUInteger i=initalValue; i>=0; i--) {

            if ([[[theButton subviews] objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[MKNumberBadgeView class]])
            {
                [[[theButton subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
                [theButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening.
There is a clue in the debug data pictured below, but I can't make sense of it.

[image]

Comment: For an *unsigned* integer, `i>=0` is *always* true. The loop never terminates and the integer "wraps around".

Comment: "AppCode does awesome code inspections" I guess they aren't so awesome after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUInteger in unsigned, so `i>=0` condition in your `for` loop always evaluates to `YES`. After `i` reach 0, on next iteration you will get integer underflow, and `i` becomes `NSUIntegerMax`.

Updated: As far as I can tell from your code, there is no reason in processing subviews in reverse order. So, you can simply do

```
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<theButton.subviews.count; i++)
```

Otherwise, you can use something like

```
if (0 == i) {
    break;
}
```

inside your loop or use `do/while` for example.

Comment: Ok, I understand now.  So what is the proposed fix?  I'm hoping for something better than simply using `int` or `NSInteger`